# Online ebooks management system that can be hosted on a server

Tags: ebook-management, server

Can you please suggest me an online book management system in PHP and MySQL, which I can host in my own Linux server? Preferably open source.

I do not intend to upload or store the ebooks but only the metadata. I want to store books details (as author, cover, genre, ISBN and description.. etc) in a database system(as mysql) to catalog, list and search them from a web platform(based on PHP for example).

If possible import details from Amazon or other sites. But this is optional.
I do not want a library management system, but a book management system. If such software doesn’t exist, can you please suggest any other alternatives?

I'm not looking for a specific website though; but something that can be hosted on a server.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I apologize for any misunderstanding. But, English is not my mother language; So you'll probably find some mistakes.

Comment: Based on your comment to the answer from @his, this question isn't very clearly written. You should edit it to clarify what, exactly, you're looking for. Also, based on that comment, couldn't you just use something like Goodreads, which already has most of that data?

Comment: Thank you for the remark; I edited it now. 
To answer you, I prefer something more independent, that I have control and can manage by myself.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure why you would need to run this on a web server; if it is just for backup reasons and distributed access I would just push the folder in one of the common online storage solutions like Dropbox or similar.

Calibre can be run as a server itself and offer the files in its library via a web interface. You can then access the files via the web browser of your reader. It works, but if you have access to a computer where you can use Calibre directly I think it is much more practical by several orders of magnitude.

But your specifications are not specific enough to tell if this solution fits your needs.

Google Play Books allows you to upload your own books so you could use this for synchronisation and distributed access also.

Comment: Thx for replying! I do not intend to upload or store the ebooks but only the metadata. I want to store books details (as author, cover, genre, ISBN and description.. etc) in a database system(as mysql) to catalog, view and search them from a web platform(based on PHP for example).

Comment: Calibre will hold all your metadata (and I would argue that storing it on a site like Goodreads, while also useful, isn't sufficient: I've had them delete my data before!), and also provides an HTTP server.

It has plugins to grab metadata from many locations, including Amazon, ISBNDB and Goodreads.

It's Free and Open Source, with a large development community. You can write your own plugins (in Python).

As for the web server: I agree that on THIS computer, I'd only want to access it directly, but I have half a dozen devices that I occasionally access it from. Then I use the web server.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [COPS](http://blog.slucas.fr/en/oss/calibre-opds-php-server) or 
[OPDSgen](http://code.google.com/p/opdsgen/).

The OPDS Format is promoted to represent book metadata.

Comment: OPDSgen source seems unavailable by now. But see [an overview of OPDS catalog generation tools](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/OPDS#OPDS_Catalog_Generation).